# How to check if given points form a continuous figure? (Python)

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib, math, geometry

I need to implement a function that takes coordinates of any number of points (in 3D space) and return **True** if points form a continuous figure. There are three figures below (in 2D space for simplicity). For the first two situations, **True** must be returned. The last one should return **False**.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It is assumed that all points in the array are located at the nodes of a square grid, the step of which is taken by the function as the second argument.

The function should look like this:

```
def is_continuous(points, step): # points is a list of tuples with coordinates
    # if points form a continuous figure:
        return True
    # else:
        return False
```

Comment: "return True if there is an adjacent point in the array for each of points (in other words, if points form a continuous figure)" - those are entirely different things. An array containing only a single point would satisfy the second condition but not the first, while your third example input would satisfy the first condition but not the second.

Comment: @user2357112 You're right, thanks. I made a mistake with the first condition, I'll delete it.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question here - can we see your code as a [mre], along with an explanation of where *specifically* in that attempt you're getting stuck? [ask]

Comment: @esqew I didn't get stuck in any particular place. I just don't understand how to implement this algorithm. I added information to the question about what the function should look like.

Comment: Isn't that just a simple DFS or BFS? And example data for clarity/testing would be good.

Comment: You could do something similar to a flood-fill algorithm, then just compare the number of nodes visited from an arbitrary starting point to the total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC and if you're tempted to use [networkx](/questions/tagged/networkx), you can try :

```
def as_grid(points):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.grid(linewidth=4, color="black", zorder=1)
    plt.scatter(*points, color="red", zorder=2, s=300)
    plt.xticks(range(-1, 8)); plt.yticks(range(-1, 8))
    plt.show()
    
def is_conn(points):
    import networkx as nx
    from libpysal import weights
    ws = weights.KNN.from_array(list(zip(*points)), k=3)
    G = ws.to_networkx().to_undirected()
    return "Connected" if nx.is_connected(G) else "Not connected"
#https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/auto_examples/geospatial/plot_points
```

*Note : The edges will vary based on the `k` nearest neighbors. For e.g, the 3rd dataset :*

[image]

If you instead want to consider an x-y `step`, maybe you can use a [`DistandBrand`](https://pysal.org/libpysal/generated/libpysal.weights.DistanceBand.html) :

```
def is_conn(points, stepx, stepy):
    import networkx as nx
    from libpysal import weights
    mdis = ((stepx)**2 + (stepy)**2)**0.5
    ws = weights.DistanceBand.from_array(list(zip(*points)), threshold=mdis)
    G = ws.to_networkx().to_undirected()
    return "Connected" if nx.is_connected(G) else "Not connected"

is_conn([x3, y3], 1, 1) #'Not connected'
is_conn([x3, y3], 2, 2) #'Connected'
```

[image]

Output :

```
for p in [(x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3)]:
    print(is_conn(p))
    as_grid(p)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Used config :

```
x1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5]
y1 = [4, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3]

x2 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
y2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 5, 6, 2, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3, 4, 5]

x3 = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]
y3 = [5, 6, 5, 6, 6, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]
```

Comment: It looks very suitable for solving this problem. I'll try to use this, thanks a lot!

Comment: Just want to wait a little to get other answers. Several ways are better than one :)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you only input points. How does this determine edges, i.e., which points are connected?

Comment: @KellyBundy, if the question be meant for me, the edges are defined by the [`weights.KNN`](https://pysal.org/libpysal/generated/libpysal.weights.KNN.html). For different `k` (*nearest neighbors*), we'll have differents edges. By the way, I can't see how the edges are defined in OP.

Comment: Some examples using the 3rd dataset : [`k=1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFUFI.png), [`k=2`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Ebu.png), [`k=3`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecb1F.png), [`k=4`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ls3pp.png) & [`k=5`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JHmu.png) (*connected*).

Comment: So if we had just two points, far apart, this code would still treat them as connected, because they're still nearest?

Comment: Yes and No. It depends on the steps defined by OP. Not sure if you noticed but the update addresses that.

Comment: Right, hadn't noticed the update. Seems more like what they want. Still not clear what they want, though. I asked them for example data for clarity, but they ignored me and I guess now that they have an answer that they accepted they'll never clarify. I wish people would just stop answering unclear questions and wait until they've been fixed...

Comment: @KellyBundy I haven't had time to try suggested methods yet. Have patience, please.

Comment: @Timeless Your method works perfectly in Python 3, including for 3D space! Thank you again! Maybe you know is there similar approach for Python 2? Unfortunately, libpysal library is not available for Python 2 and the alternative Pysal doen't have to_networkx method...

Comment: @KellyBundy, I hear what you're saying and I take not of that ;). ae_fed, glad it worked but I don't have any Python 2 alternative to propose.

Comment: @Timeless Thank you very much anyway! On python 3 it works exactly as I need

Answer (score 1):

I believe the OP goal is simply to know whether there is only one contiguous figure. If that is the case, a possible solution with no external libraries is:

- keep a list of the figures found so far
- for each point, check whether it is linked to a previous point (i.e. linked diagonally or vertically to a point in the previous row, or horizontally to a point in the previous column), then if the point:

  - has no links, add it to a new figure
  - has one or more links to points included in exactly one figure, add it to that figure
  - has links to points included in different figures, merge that figures and add the point

```
def cont_figure(width, height, points):
    grid = [[0 for w in range(width)] for h in range(height)]
    for no, pt in enumerate(points, start=1):
        grid[pt[0]][pt[1]] = no
    figures = []
    for no, pt in enumerate(points, start=1):
        links = []
        if pt[0] > 0 and grid[pt[0]-1][pt[1]]:
            links.append(grid[pt[0]-1][pt[1]])
        if pt[1] > 0 and grid[pt[0]][pt[1]-1]:
            links.append(grid[pt[0]][pt[1]-1])
        if pt[0] > 0 and pt[1] > 0 and grid[pt[0]-1][pt[1]-1]:
            links.append(grid[pt[0]-1][pt[1]-1])
        if pt[0] < width-2 and pt[1] > 0 and grid[pt[0]+1][pt[1]-1]:
            links.append(grid[pt[0]+1][pt[1]-1])
        pt_figs = sorted({fig_no for fig_no, figure in enumerate(figures) for link in links if link in figure})
        if not pt_figs:
            figures.append([no])
        elif len(pt_figs) == 1:
            figures[pt_figs[0]].append(no)
        else:
            for fig_no in range(len(pt_figs)-1,0,-1):
                figures[fig_no-1] += figures[fig_no]
                figures[fig_no-1].append(no)
                del(figures[fig_no])
    return len(figures) == 1
```